# Write data to file using AWS kinesis-firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am having a node app that writes data to s3 using firehose stream. I am using the putRecord method for the same. The objects are successfully entered to s3 bucket.
However instead of objects I want to write the data to a file (.txt format).
Is there some method to write from stream to s3 as text file?
Update the s3 object from kinesis-firehose.
Also sometimes firehose makes multiple entries to one record. If I write after a minute's interval or longer it generates new records. Is there a way to ensure that each entry is stored as new object irrespective of intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Kinesis Firehose is the wrong tool for your usecase, since it has a mininum buffer interval of 1 minute. If you want single objects, why don't you use the S3 SDK?